# How do upper layers of urethane adhere or bond to lower layers after curing?

Tags: adhesion

I have been painting fine art subject matter, mostly on wooden panels, with urethane (not polyurethane) for a number of years and it has turned out to be a useful medium, particularly because it's not gummy like acrylic and can be occasionaly lightly sanded. I understand the urethane I use may cure ("dry") after 24 hours and perhaps longer, depending on the humidity. In a semi-wet state, the layers meld, which seems obvious and intuitive. The urethane can dry pretty flat if brushed on relatively evenly, which gives rise to the question of whether the adhesion is a physical bond - as a layman I picture a bumpy molecular upper surface settling into a bumpy lower layer molecular surface -- but that notion would not necessarily explain why one layer wouldn't fall off if one turns the painting upside down. So perhaps there are chemical electrical bonds being formed -- but how would they bond if the layer is no longer wet -- are the bonds physical after all? Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Urethane is a liquid. in hardening it polymerizes, becoming *poly*urethane.
2. If a layer is allowed to completely polymerize, the next layer does not adhere as strongly to the first, unless it sanded before applying, to provide that bumpy layer you describe.
3. Adhesion is a powerful force. Even without chemically combining, the two layers are still attracted electrostatically. Certainly, the second layer will not simply fall off, just as [decal placed on glass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ZNEkDkypNU) adheres.

   A classic experiment to show the strength of adhesion is to [take two clean glass microscope slides, put a drop of water between](https://serc.carleton.edu/sp/library/demonstrations/examples/surfacetension.html), and *quickly* pull them apart. The adhesion between glass and water is sufficient to snap one of the slides.
4. That said, after sufficient weathering or abrasion, the second layer is likely to start to peel off.